# Help needed in proving a corollary of hilbert nullstellansatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question was left as an exercise in my class of algebraic geometry and I am not able to prove it.

> If  L is a field extension of K , $R=K[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a polynomial algebra over K in n indeterminates and A is a ideal in ring R.  Define $V_L (A) = ${$ x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in L^n |$ for all $f \in A$} and  $I_K (Y)= ${$ f\in R= K[x_1,...,x_n] | f(y)=0 $ for all $y\in Y$}.

Then show that $ \cap_{i\in I} V_L (A_i) = V_L( \sum_{i\in I} A_i)$ where $V_L$ is a map from r- I(R)  to K-algebraic sets.

Also, show that  $I_K (\cap_{i\in I} V_i) \supseteq  \sqrt{ \sum_{i\in I} I_K (V_i)}$

Attempt: For both of this questions I tried by taking an element in the RHS and LHS and then using the definition given above but  I am not able to make any progress.

Question :   If L is algebraically closed. Then the map $ L^n \to  r-I(R)$, $V \to I_K(V)$ is bijective and  $I_K ( \cap_{i\in I} V_i ) \subseteq \sqrt{ \sum_{i\in I} I_K(V_i)}$ ( here ,r-I(R) = the set of all radical ideals in R)

I have proved the map to be 1-1 using hilbert nullstellansatz but I am not sure how to prove that it is onto and the inequality.

**Can you please help me with above questions by giving hints?**

Comment: $I_K$ of anything is reduced, so the second question amounts to showing that every $I_K(V_i)$ is contained in $I_K(\cap_j{V_j})$. For the first question, $x \in \cap_j V_K(A_j) \Leftrightarrow \forall j\, \forall f \in A_j,\, f(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow \forall f \in \sum_j{A_j},\, f(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow x \in V_K(\sum_j{A_j})$.

Comment: @Aphelli Can you also help me for the remaining 2 question?

Comment: @Aphelli I have understood your answer of 1st question.